# Reusing a custom ContentPart in the same ContentType

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle a requirement I have for an Orchard module I'm building.

I have a ContentPart that has a few fields. One field is a ContentPicker that allows for multiple items to be associated to the part. The rest are descriptive information.

The issue I have is that I actually need to be able to include more than one of this ContentPart into a ContentType. I need to create a ContentType that has exactly 3 of this part.

Should I be making this into a field instead of a part? Is it even possible to have a ContentField that has other fields in it?

Or, should I somehow use all the same models and data structures, but somehow define it as 3 distinct parts?

Just wondering what the best practice to do something like this would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one part of each kind on a given type. You can't have fields that have other fields in it (instead - take an existing field and extend it with custom stuff).

As I understand, the actual problem is *"how to make groups of fields with some metadata for each group"*, right? If so, there are a few approaches to solve the problem:

- **Create a custom field based on Content Picker** (basically - take existing Content Picker and extend it with your metadata) and use this without the need for a separate part
- **Create one part to hold only the metadata for each field attached to it** and attach 1 or more fields to it
- **Create 3 distinct parts.** Parts should be thought of as extensions that add some unique features to an item. If you think it's logically ok to have 3 parts then go for it.

Comment: Both fields and parts can have properties.

Comment: The first option you've suggested is the most direct, and IMO elegant, way to handle this. Thanks!

Thanks for the additional information on parts and fields Bertrand